# problem with creating list of longtables

Tags: tables, longtable

I'm using the `longtables` for my document without `\begin{table} ... \end{table}`.

How can I create the list of tables?
Command `\listoftables` doesn't work.

Comment: `longtable` uses the same auxiliary file as other tables: `lot`. You can define a new floating environment e.g. with `newfloat` and than change the file extension from `lot` to your definition in `\LT@c@ption`

Comment: `\listoftables` lists caption commands, it is the same with `table` and `longtable` you need a `\caption` otherwise it is not listed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using `\tcaption` maybe that's why it doesn't work?

Comment: OK, sorry, I have figured out that command `\tcaption` is custom command in our publishing company template, and it doesn't write information about tables in lot file.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the issue was caused by using a custom caption command instead of \caption{}.